# Como puedo obtener la respuesta de una API en Svelte

Tags: javascript, aplicación-web, asp.net-web-api, frontend, svelte

aun no soy muy habil en svelte y tengo esta duda.
como puedo almacenar la respuesta de una API en una variable para hacer una comparacion?
el envio de la info a la api ya lo hice pero no se como capturar la respuesta.

```
getAuthorizedUserPassword : async (AuthorizedUserPassword) =>
HttpRequest.get(`${apiUrl}/api/Auth/${AuthorizedUserPassword}`),
```

ese es el codigo para hacer el envio pero no se como capturar la respuesta

con postman lo hago y me retorna esto

```
{
    "data": {
        "password": true
    }
}
```

que es lo que quiero, esa variale password la quiero almacenar en una variable en Svelte para poder hacer la comparacion y ejecutar otra funcion.

hice esto pero no me funciono... creo.

```
let statePass = 
  {
    password: null,
  };
  const getPasswordUser = () =>
  PackagingApi.getAuthorizedUserPassword(PasswordImput)
  .then((data) => (response = {data.response}))
  .catch(handleError);

  const AuthorizedUserPassword = async (AuthorizedUserPassword) =>{
  if(AuthorizedUserPassword)
  {
    PackagingApi.getAuthorizedUserPassword()
    .then((data) => (statePass = data))
    .catch(handleError);
    getPasswordUser();
  }
};
```

y lo quiero implementar aqui.

```
function unlockLinewhile(){unlockLine()}

function unlockLine() {
            PackagingApi.SetStationBlocked(1,lineCode)
            //Ingresamos una pregunta o mensaje
            var psswd = prompt("Linea Bloqueada \n Ingresa la contraseña del supervisor", "");
            //Verificamos si el usuario ingreso un valor
            if (psswd == "12345"){
            PackagingApi.SetStationBlocked(0,lineCode)
            //alert("Tu fruta favorita es ");
            }
            //Verificamos si el usuario NO ingreso un valor
            else if(psswd == null || psswd != "12345") {
            alert("Contraseña Incorrecta \n Ingresa la contraseña Correcta para desbloquear");
            unlockLinewhile();
            }
        }
```

para en el if poder comparar si es true o false que ejecute la siguiente funcion.

de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método then de una promesa para almacenar la respuesta de la API en una variable y hacer la comparación que necesitas.

```
let password = null;

const getAuthorizedUserPassword = (AuthorizedUserPassword) => {
  return PackagingApi.getAuthorizedUserPassword(AuthorizedUserPassword)
    .then((response) => {
      password = response.data.password;
      return password;
    })
    .catch(handleError);
};

const unlockLine = () => {
  PackagingApi.SetStationBlocked(1, lineCode);
  const psswd = prompt("Linea Bloqueada \n Ingresa la contraseña del supervisor", "");

  if (psswd == "12345") {
    PackagingApi.SetStationBlocked(0, lineCode);
  } else if (psswd == null || psswd != "12345") {
    getAuthorizedUserPassword(psswd)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response && response.data && response.data.password !== undefined) {
          if (response.data.password) {
            PackagingApi.SetStationBlocked(0, lineCode);
          } else {
            alert("Contraseña Incorrecta \n Ingresa la contraseña Correcta para desbloquear");
            unlockLine();
          }
        } else {
          alert("Error al obtener la respuesta de la API");
        }
      });
  }
}
        }
      });
  }
};


Guardas la respuesta de la API en la variable password dentro de la función getAuthorizedUserPassword. Luego, en la función unlockLine, hacemos la comparación para verificar si la contraseña ingresada es correcta o no. Si no es correcta, llamamos a la función getAuthorizedUserPassword para obtener la respuesta de la API y hacer la comparación.
```

Comment: me gusto tu respuesta amigo, ya viendo vien ese codigo tiene mas logica, pero me aparecio un el siguiente mensaje.
que dice lo siguiente:
TypeError:cannot read properties of undefined (reading password')

Comment: @RogelioArriaga ahi corregi el codigo para que realice una verificación primero que la respuesta de la API no es undefined y que sus propiedades data y password también no son undefined

Comment: Muchas gracias @David Gomez, tu ejemplo de codigo me funciono perfectamente, solo le hice unos cambios minimos y me ayudo bastante, mi problema se soluciono, Muchas gracias :D

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar ; [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido)

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias @David Gomez

El codigo funciono muy bien solo le agregue unos detalles adicionales
le agregue el

```
const data =  response.json()
```

abajo del return en la funcion getAuthorizedUserPassword

y le agregue un if adicional despues del if (response)

```
 const unlockLinewhile = () => {unlockLine()} //Constante que se ejecuta al 
 momento de un alert() que a su vez manda allamar a otra constante.

 let Isavailablepassword = null;
 const getAuthorizedUserPassword = (AuthorizedUserPassword) => {
 return PackagingApi.getAuthorizedUserPassword(AuthorizedUserPassword)
  const data =  response.json()
  .then((response) => {
  Isavailablepassword = response.data.password;
  return isavailablepassword;
  })
  .catch(handleError);
};

const unlockLine = () => {
            PackagingApi.SetStationBlocked(1,lineCode) //Bloqueamos toda la linea
            let imputpassword = prompt("Linea Bloqueada \n Ingresa la contraseña del supervisor", ""); //Entrada de contraseña
            getAuthorizedUserPassword(imputpassword)
            .then((response) => {
              if(response)
              {
                  if(response.password == true){
                  PackagingApi.SetStationBlocked(0, lineCode);  
                  }
                  else{
                    alert("Contraseña Incorrecta \n Ingresa la contraseña Correcta para desbloquear");
                    unlockLine();
                  }
              } 
            });
          };
```